# Behavior of Character Array in C when integer is present

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am not able to get the output of this program means how this program runs? Can anybody help me in this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
char c[]={'1','2','3',0,'1','2','3'};
printf(c); //gives 123 as output
char d[]={'1','0','3',0,'1','2','3'};
printf(d); //gives 103 as output
return 0;
}
```

This gives output as a string all the characters that I have inserted before 0.
I would also like an explanation for why the printf is printing all the characters before 0?

Comment: Wrong argument for printf. It should be a string. 0 is the end of a string in C.

Answer (score 4):

You have a `0` in your array in the middle. `printf` will print up to the first `0` in your `char` array. Also, you can't have multiple characters in single quotes. Single quotes define chars not strings. Finally, you should end your `char` array with a `0`.

Try this:

```
char c[]={'1','4','3','3','0','1','2','3',0};
```

Note that there are quotes around the `0` in the middle to make it a character and there are **no** quotes around the final `0` to end the string.

Comment: Then why is it printing all the characters before 0? I understood that the character array ends when it sees a 0 but why is printf doing so?

Comment: @VaibhavAgarwal what would be the expected behavior otherwise?

Comment: That's how strings work in C. You should look it up. A string is simply a char array with a 0 marking the end. `printf` requires a string (a pointer to the first char to be precise), so it prints up until the first 0 in your array. You have to end the array with a 0, because otherwise it will continue printing garbage until it finds a 0 in memory, which is not what you want.

Comment: Should not it print the beginning address of array?

Comment: What would it? `printf` prints a string you pass it. If you want to print the adress of your char array, try this: `printf("%p", c))`. `%p` is the format specifier for a pointer adress and you pass it the array as an argument.

Comment: "you can't have multiple characters in single quotes" Euh, but yes you can.

Comment: Also note that `'0'` and `0` is not the same. Strings end with the *value* `0`, not the *character* `'0'`. If you look up the value of the character `'0'` in an [ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), you'll see that it's actually 30.

Comment: @H2CO3 Technically yes. But I'm pretty sure it's not what he wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding 0 equates (usually) to `NULL`, printf prints till the first `NULL` terminator it finds.

In your case

```
char c[]={'1','2','3',0,'1','2','3'};
printf(c);
char d[]={'1','0','3',0,'1','2','3'};
printf(d);
```

when printing `c` and `d` printf prints till the first `NULL` it encounters which is `0`. However when you put `'0'` it sees it as a character 0 not a terminator.